# Detecting duplicate entries in a JSON list of objects

Tags: java, json, list, object, duplicates

I have a JSON file being parsed in java. It has several lists of objects like the following:

```
{
    "phoneNumbers": [
        {
            "type": "home",
            "number": "212 555-1234"
        },
        {
            "type": "home",
            "number": "212 555-1234"
        },
        {
            "type": "fax",
            "number": "646 555-4567"
        }
    ]
}
```

It's a sensitive input file and overwriting duplicate entries is not an option. The program checks for duplicates using a for loop and maps when processing a particular list, but I want to check the entire file for dups in one go as the file is being parsed so that in case of error the program stops before running anything else.

I was wondering if there's a JSON parser for java out there that will detect duplicate object entries in the list and provide a message. Also, are there any parsers that will let you know if a declared object gets overwritten because another object with the same name is declared in the same file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core) does have a [deserialization feature](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Deserialization-Features) in its [data binding extension](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) that will do what you need: `FAIL_ON_READING_DUP_TREE_KEY` will cause the parser to fail on reading a duplicate key.

That said, you can probably implement the same functionality for any parser that supports deserializing into custom objects by using a custom [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) class that throws an exception if a duplicate key is encountered, rather than just update the value...

As for finding duplicate entries in the list, how about deserializing into a custom [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) subclass that throws an exception if a duplicate entry is inserted?

Comment: Thanks this helps! For checking duplicates in arrays I found a json schema validation keyword called uniqueItems, and it seems to work properly.